ipa file crashing after adding cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin
I have a ios cordova app using the plugin cordova-plugin-firebasex, when run from Xcode the app works fine, notifications are also received.
But when archived and ipa file is installed the app crashes
Cordova Version : 12.0.0
iOS Platform Version : 7.1.1
Xcode Version : 15.4
cordova-plugin-firebasex : 16.5.0
